# Normalize NYT upshot precinct geojson data

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have never worked with json files before. I am trying to normalize the following json file so that I can have a dataframe with precinct-level granularity that includes votes_total.

https://int.nyt.com/newsgraphics/elections/map-data/2020/national/precincts-with-results.geojson.gz

I am currently using this code:

```
with open('precincts-with-results.geojson.gz','r', encoding="utf8") as f:
data = json.loads(f.read())

# Flatten data
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['features'])
```

The output I would like would be a data frame with these columns:

```
  'GEOID',
  'votes_dem',
  'votes_rep',
  'votes_total'
  'votes_per_sqkm',
  'pct_dem_lead'
```

help appreciated!

Comment: kindly post your epxected ouptut in a dataframe form. pls do not post pics

Comment: @sammywemmy I updated the cols I am looking for within the dataframe.

Comment: @sammywemmy  got some json mate (:-

Comment: kindly provide a small sample of the data